# Linux capabilities to launch process as root from a user mode program in C++

Tags: c++, linux, linux-capabilities

I am trying to launch a child-process as root from a non-root parent-process. I am thinking to use capabilities to make that work.

What I have tried so far is that, have set the file cap *`permitted`* for parent process to `cap_setgid,cap_setuid,capkill+p`. Then on the same parent process, I am programmatically setting the same capabilities to effective capability of the process before calling `fork+exec` from the parent process.

For sanity check, I have changed the chmod permission of my child-process to load as root only `chmod 4755`. Thus, it will only be executed as root and nothing else.

I am seeing that with these a setup, I am not been able to load the child process at all. Can anyone help me understand, what am I misisng here?

Comment: "*I am trying to launch a child-process as root from a non-root parent-process*" - sounds like a security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: @RemyLebeau not necessaily, these apps are installed and store in privileged directories and cannot be changed without root privileges.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you please give steps to reproduce?

Comment: @thatotherguy what exactly you are trying to reproduce?

Comment: Your problem according to your description

Comment: @thatotherguy okay. So even I’m having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Maybe you used different commands or source code, and that's why we're seeing different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (`parent.cc`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    cap_t caps = cap_get_proc();
    cap_value_t val = CAP_SETUID;
    cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, 1, &val, CAP_SET);
    if (cap_set_proc(caps)) {
        perror("failed to raise cap_setuid");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setuid(0)) {
        perror("unable to setuid");
        exit(1);
    }
    execl("./child.sh", "child.sh", NULL);
    std::cout << "didn't work, uid=" << getuid();
    exit(1);
}
```

With this (`child.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
id -u
```

Build and set things up:

```
$ chmod +x child.sh
$ g++ -o parent parent.cc -lcap
$ sudo setcap cap_setuid=p ./parent
```

If you run `./parent` it should work like this:

```
$ ./parent 
0
```

This example is single threaded. If your app is single threaded, it should be sufficient. If your program is multithreaded, you might need to explore something like [libpsx](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/who-ordered-libpsx).

Comment: Awesome this solved my problem. I missed `setuid(0)`